# ListView com checkbox, botão selecionar todos e nenhum

Tags: android, listview

Tenho um listview com check box

[image]

Estou querendo colocar um checkbox em cima da lista. Aí quando selecionar ele, quero selecionar tudo da lista e quando clicar para tirar a seleção quero tirar a seleção de toda a lista.

Como fazer isso?

Este e o XML que criei para ser o *layout* de cada item da lista

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Aqui eu seto o adapter, a lista passada como parâmetro tem o nome e o número do destinatário.

```
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.item_list_info, lista);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta criares um `layout` com `checkbox` e colocares antes da lista. E ao clicares nessa `checkbox` por todas as `checkbox` a `true` no teu `MyCustomAdapter`:

```
novacheckbox.onclick()
{
    int item=0;
    while ( item < dataAdapter.getCount() )
    {
         listView.setItemChecked(item, true);
         item++;
    }
}
```